# New Suggested Edit review queue buttons look blurry in IE 8

Tags: support, bug, status-declined, review, design

When you first are shown a question in the Suggested Edit review queue, the Approve, Reject and Improve buttons (which are disabled for the first second or two) now look like this:

[image: blurry image here]

And then when the buttons are enabled, they look like this:

[image: not-so-blurry image]

Maybe I'm being overly picky, but the "disabled" buttons look fairly blurry and/or out-of-focus, and is pretty jarring to see.

It only lasts a second or two before the buttons become enabled, but surely there must be a better way to show disabled buttons.  I know, I know, it just rolled out, but still...

**EDIT:**  This may only be impacting Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: Your 3D glasses haven't come in the mail yet? I've got mine, and those buttons look _good_.

Comment: No, I just my sticker last week, I expect the glasses may take a while.

Comment: Hmm, what browser? This is what it looks like to me: http://i.imgur.com/0Iwd47N.png (I'm on Chrome)

Comment: Looks fine in IE9 (by which I mean, uglier than Chrome/Firefox, less ugly than this). The background *should* be gray.

Comment: @Bart -- wow, that's pretty different. This is on IE 8; the buttons do look fine on my Droid. I've edited my title.  Don't know if this is more appropriate as `Support` or `Bug`.

Comment: @Shog9 - yup, I see that when reviewing from my phone. On my browser, they're all dark gray; the background color never changes, the font just shifts one pixel up and left when "enabled". I've uploaded a before-and-after picture.

Comment: They're not going to push a fix that only affects IE8. ;P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE8 is no longer a supported browser, so we won't be fixing this explicitly.

I think it might have been fixed incidentally (at least IE10's IE8 compatibility mode thinks it has been, for whatever's that worth).

Comment: No, I just tested, it's still fugly in an IE8 browser, but fortunately we've actually gotten out of the stone age and updated our browsers.